# Coverting array to indexed object in typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript, types

I have an array of the following type.

```
interface IArray {
   id: "message1" | "message2" | "message3";
   message: string;
}

const myArray: IArray[] = [
   {
      id: "message1",
      message: "Here is your message 1"
   },
   {
      id: "message2",
      message: "Here is your message 2"
   }
]
```

I would like to convert it to an indexed object with types as following.

```
const myObject = {
   message1: "Here is your message 1",
   message2: "Here is your message 2"
}
```

I could write a function that converts the array into an object.

```
const myObject: any = {};
myArray.forEach((arrElement) => {
   myObject[arrElement.id] = arrElement.message;
});
```

But the `myObject` is of type `any`. while I want the `myObject` to have type with indexed `keys` depending on array `id` type.

Comment: what is `indexed object `

Comment: What you mean by "_But the objects keys do not get indexed with_"?

Comment: An indexed object - in typescript defined object types have indexes.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const myArray = [{key: "message1",message: "Here is your message 1"},{key: "message2",message: "Here is your message 2"}]
const result = myArray.reduce((a,b)=>{
  a[b.key]=b.message;
  return a
}, {});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Please I need a typescript solution. This is not typescript.
Note: I need definitions

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method:

**JavaScript:**

```js
let myArray = [{
    id: "message1",
    message: "Here is your message 1"
  },
  {
    id: "message2",
    message: "Here is your message 2"
  }
];
let myObject = {};
myArray.forEach(item => {
  myObject[item.id] = item.message;
});
console.log(myObject);
```

**TypeScript:**

```
interface IArray {
  id: "message1" | "message2" | "message3";
  message: string;
}
const myArray: IArray[] = [{
    id: "message1",
    message: "Here is your message 1"
  },
  {
    id: "message2",
    message: "Here is your message 2"
  }
];
let myObject: any = {};
myArray.forEach(item => {
  myObject[item.id] = item.message;
});
console.log(myObject);
```

Comment: Please I need a typescript solution. This is not typescript.
Note: I need definitions

Comment: @TanmoyBasak I have updated my answer with a TypeScript syntax.

Comment: Thank you for the code. However, the resulting `myObject` has a type of `any`. While I am looking for a type:
`interface IObject {
   message1: string;
   message2: string;
}`